# Change Data Capture using HIVE

Tags: hive, cdc

i'm trying to do change data capture using hive. We already have an existing CDC in DataStage, but we are trying to implement in HIVE now.
 Here is what I have done, please correct me if im doing something wrong. (but im getting the correct results... :)

Here is the source data:
table Name: month1
    e_id, e_name, e_ad
    11, john, singapore
    22, jack, Melbourne
    33, jessy, sydney
    44, lampard, canada
    55, pomer, perth

second table: month2
it has the same columns as month1.
e_id, e_name, e_add
11, john, odisha
22, jack, Melbourne
44, lampard, canada
55, pomer, perth
66, rahul, mumbai

so here the key field is the e_id, and value field is e_name and e_add

```
select 
case when cdc_codes ='Updates' Then month2s
case when cdc_codes = 'NoChange' then month1s
case when cdc_codes = 'New' then month2s
case when cdc_codes = 'Deletes' then month1s
else 'Error' end as fin_cols
from (select case when m1.e_id = m2.e_id and concat(m1.e_name,m1.e_add) = concat(m2.e_name,m2.e_add)     then  'NoChange'
when m1.e_id = m2.e_id and  concat(m1.e_name,m1.e_add) <> concat(m2.e_name,m2.e_add) then  'Update'
when m1.e_id is null then 'New'
when m2.e_id is null then 'Deletes'
else 'Error' end as cdc_codes,
concat(m1.e_id,',',m1.e_name,',',m1.e_add) as month1s,
concat(m2.e_id,',',m2.e_name,',',m2.e_add) as month2s
from month1 as m1 full outer join month2 as m2
on m1.e_id = m2.e_id) as b1
```

this SQL works fine and im getting my expected results. please forgive me for the poor column naming conventions.  Once i get a confirmation about the solution, i will re-write this SQL and post the final clean version.

Comment: do you have some problems or getting any errors? otherwise this question is more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Arghtype, thanks for the reply. Im not getting any error here, im getting the correct/desired output. But i just wanted to make sure that the code looks ok and can be put to action. Also im new to stackoverflow.com, so i didnt know that there was a codereview section.